# create boolean mask of numpy rgb array if matches color

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rgb

I want to identify all the yellow pixels that lie between two colours, for example [255, 255, 0] is bright yellow, and [200, 200, 50] is a mid yellow.

```
c = color_array = np.array([ 
  [255, 255, 0],  # bright yellow
  [200, 200, 50]])  # mid yellow
```

So the rgb ranges could be represented as :

```
(min, max) tuple... 
r (200, 255)
g (200, 255)
b (0, 50)
```

I have a 2D (height of image x width of image) [r, g, b] array:

```
image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 4, 3))
array([[[169, 152,  65],
    [ 46, 123,  39],
    [116, 190, 227],
    [ 95, 138, 243]],
   [[120,  75, 156],
    [ 94, 168, 139],
    [131,   0,   0],
    [233,  43,  28]],
   [[195,  65, 198],
    [ 33, 161, 231],
    [125,  31, 101],
    [ 56, 123, 151]],
   [[118, 124, 220],
    [241, 221, 137],
    [ 71,  65,  23],
    [ 91,  75, 178]],
   [[153, 238,   7],
    [  2, 154,  45],
    [144,  33,  94],
    [ 52, 188,   4]]])
```

I'd like to produce a 2D array with True if the r,g,b values are in the range between the 2 color values in the color arrays.

```
[[T, F, F, T], 
 [T, F, F, T],
  ...       ]]
```

I've been struggling to get the indexing right.

Comment: Can you make your array say `5x4` instead of `5x3`? That would make it much more clear that the 3rd dimension is the color.

Comment: Why is `color_array` 4-dimensional?

Comment: Can you specify very clearly what it means to be within range? Does it mean `255 >= r >= 200 and 255 >= g >= 200 and 0 <= g <= 50`?

Comment: Just changed the dimension, agree that's clearer.  So this would result in a 5x4 boolean array, where the colour matches as follows:if the r, g, b colour was  200 < r < 255, 200 < g < 255, 0 < b < 50

Comment: @BlueShrapnel. Just to be clear, you want to match *all* the conditions, not *any* or "at least two" or something weird like that, right?

Comment: For yellow, it would be all, but to find red, it would just the be the r value.  And for green, the g value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine several ways to tackle this:

The **one way** would be to compare all elements individually:

```
c = color_array

within_box = np.all(
    np.logical_and(
        np.min(c, axis=0) < image,
        image < np.max(c, axis=0)
    ),
    axis=-1
)
```

This will be `True` for all pixels where

```
200 < R < 255 and 200 < G < 255 and 0 < B < 50
```

This is equivalent to looking for all pixels inside a small subset (a box), defined by `color_array`, in the [RGB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) (a bigger box).

An **alternative solution** would be to take the line between the two points in `color_array`, and [calculate each pixel's individual euclidean distance to that line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840030/distance-between-point-and-a-line-from-two-points):

```
distance = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(c[1,:] - c[0,:], c[0,:] - image), axis=-1)/np.linalg.norm(c[1,:] - c[0,:])
```

Afterwards you can find all pixels that are within a certain distance to that line, i.e.

```
within_distance = distance < 25
```

A **third solution** is to calculate the euclidean distance of each pixel to the mean value of your two colors:

```
distance_to_mean = np.linalg.norm(image - np.mean(c, axis=0), axis=-1)
```

finding all pixels within a limit can then interpreted as finding all pixels in a sphere around the average color of your two limit colors. E.g. if you chose the distance to be half the distance between the two points

```
within_sphere = distance_to_mean < (np.linalg.norm(c) / 2)
```

you get all pixels that fall in *a sphere for wich both limiting colors exactly touch the opposite ends of the surface*.

And of course if you want all pixels that are **perceptually similar** to your two limit colors, you should convert your data to a perceptual color space, like Lab

```
import skimage
image_lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(image / 255)
color_array_lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(color_array[np.newaxis, ...] / 255)
```

and do the computations in that space instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just working through your suggestions to see if I understand how they work.

Comment: Really like the sphere approach, also easy to conceptualise.

Comment: I've added a distance measure to the sphere approach, for wich the sphere is exactly spanned by the two limiting colors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not particularly elegant, but should work:

```
def color_mask(array, r_lim, g_lim, b_lim):
    """
    array : m x n x 3 array of colors
    *_lim are 2-element tuples, where the first element is expected to be <= the second.
    """
    r_mask = ((array[..., 0] >= r_lim[0]) & (array[..., 0] <= r_lim[1]))
    g_mask = ((array[..., 1] >= g_lim[0]) & (array[..., 1] <= g_lim[1]))
    b_mask = ((array[..., 2] >= b_lim[0]) & (array[..., 2] <= b_lim[1]))
    return r_mask & g_mask & b_mask
```

You could easily extend this to handle arbitrary numbers of colors in the last dimension using numpy's broadcasting rules:

```
def color_mask(array, *lims):
    lims = np.asarray(lims)
    lower = (array >= lims[:, 0])
    upper = (array <= lims[:, 1])
    return np.logical_and.reduce(upper & lower, axis=2)
```