# Distance between Linear Regression slope and data point

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have fit a `LinearRegression()` model. What I want to do now is basically calculate the distance between some data points and the regression line.

My datapoints are two dimensional points **(x, y)**

My question is: How can I get the equation of the line from the `LinearRegression()` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), use `clf.coef_` for the weight vector(s) and `clf.intercept_` for the bias:

> `coef_` : array, shape `(n_features, )` or `(n_targets, n_features)`
>   Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple
>   targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape
>   `(n_targets, n_features)`, while if only one target is passed, this is a
>   1D array of length `n_features`.
>
> `intercept_` : array Independent term in
>   the linear model.

Once you have these, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840218/4909087).

Comment: Somehow I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After you have fit the model, you can either call the `coef` and `intercept_` attributes to see what the coefficients and the intercept are respectively.

But this would involve writing a constructed formula for your model. My recommendation is once you build your model, make the predictions and score it against the true `y` values -

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred) # y_test are true values, y_pred are the predictions that you get by calling regression.predict()
```

If the goal is to calculate distances, you `sklearn.metrics` convenience functions instead of looking for the equation and hand-computing it yourself. The manual way to do that will be -

```
import numpy as np
y_pred = np.concatenate(np.ones(X_test.shape[0]), X_test) * np.insert(clf.coef_,0,clf.intercept_)
sq_err = np.square(y_pred - y_test)
mean_sq_err = np.mean(sq_err)
```

Comment: I'm basically looking for normal distance between the point and the line and obtain a score for it - since the data is 2D this is literally doing a poor man's PCA.