# Measure distance to edge given point

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, dlib

We're trying to measure the distance from a pupil pixel to a glass frame.

Right now, we can obtain the [pupil's position and the direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxCZt.png) in which we need to search, using simple Dlib or OpenCV functions.

I'm considering using a line iterator to go down until we find the frame, but what would be the most robust way of detecting it?
The goal is to get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbRDw.png)

EDIT: I'm assuming I can always obtain [this kind of picture quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqmGo.png)

Comment: what's the technique used to detect the glass frame ? 
the distance between line and a point can be computed using this formula https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840218/4578111

Comment: that's part of the question: what would be a robust way to detect it?

Comment: that totally depends on how well you capture the face. any information on lighting conditions ? face positions ?

Comment: please check the edited question