# Check if values are inside a specific area around a predefined linear function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My research on solving my issue was unfortunately unsuccessful and I hope you can help me. I have defined the following linear function for a straight line

```
x = [298358.3258395831, 298401.1779180078]
y = [5625243.628060675, 5625347.074197255]
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

and I want to check, if values in an array are inside an area around this function. The area around the function could look like this:

[image: linear function]

I couldn't find a solution how to create an area around this straight line function and so I couldn't find a way how to check if the points in the array are inside or outside of the area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or is it better to define two parallel line functions and do the comparison with the generated area in between these functions?

Comment: I would break it down in a few steps: finding the transformation making the rectangle horizontal, applying it to your band and your array, using the formula check if a point is inside an horizontal box.

Comment: your area is not given by two lines starting and ending on the same x values.

Comment: One possibilty is to use one function and let's say we create an area with +-5 (so bidirectional) around it or only one way with e.g. +10 in one direction. Another possibility would be to create a parallel function and create the area in between and there wouldn't be any intersections of these two functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a line given by the equation `ax + by + c = 0`, the distance from a point `A = (x_a,y_a)` to this line is given by the following formula :

```
dist = np.abs(a * x_a + b * y_a + c) / np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Source [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

That way, if you have an array of points and a threshold above which you consider your points to be too far away from your line, you can simply do :

```
array_points = ... # Format : [[x_1,y_1], [x_2,y_2],...]
a, b, c = ... # Your line's parameters here
thresh = 1e-2 # For example

def is_close_line(array, threshold) :
  array_dist = np.abs(a * array[:,0] + b * array[:,1] + c) / np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
  return (array_dist < threshold)
```

`is_close_line(array_points, thresh)` will then output a boolean array, where the `i`-th item indicates wether or not the `i`-th element of `array_points` is close to your line.

Comment: Your approach looks like that what I would like to have and I comprehend it but I am messing up with the equations... I constructed a straight line in the form f(x) = mx + b with those two given points x and y (which are UTM coordinates) and if I transfer it to ax + bx + c = 0 this would give m = -(a/b) and my_b = -(c/your_b). Using your answer would mean that I have to solve a 3x3 system of linear equations to get a, b and c. I think I am missunderstanding the relation between both linear equations...

Comment: No no no, it's far much simple ! You have `a = m`, `my_b = -1` and `c = your_b`. That's it ! As your line is currently on the format `y = f(x) = mx + your_b`. The notations overlaps, my bad, but forget about your initials `x` and `y` points.

Comment: It felt a little bit wrong but I tested it with two simple samples and it worked for both cases. So thanks to you at this point. Another approach I've found would be to take the inverse of `m` to get an orthogonal straight line to the given linear function and equalize both functions to get the closest point to the given point `A = (x_a,y_a)`. Then you just have to calculate the distance between both points.

Comment: Yup that should also work, with a little bit more of calculations though as you'd have to project your point onto this orthogonal line.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be:

- Take a distance and project it onto the x axis
- Build two new lines by shifting your line according to the distance projection
- Compare a new point with the so-built lines

Here a sample code (note that m=0 should be handled differently):

```
def near_line(point, dist, m, b):
    # Data preparation
    x, y = point
    dist = abs(dist)
    
    if m != 0:
        # Case positive ramp
        dist_projection = dist/np.sin(np.arctan(abs(m)))
        return m*(x-dist_projection)+b < y < m*(x+dist_projection)+b
    
    else:
        # Case horizontal line
        return b-dist < y < b+dist


print( near_line([298359, 5625244], dist=5, m=m, b=b) )
print( near_line([298400, 5625250], dist=5, m=m, b=b) )
```

Out:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840030/distance-between-point-and-a-line-from-two-points) where the concept of cross-product and norm are considered. This solution applies also to an infinite line like yours, where it's constructed starting from two points.

```
import numpy as np

def dist_array_line(a, l1, l2, threshold):
    """
    a : numpy.array
        Array of points of shape (M,2)
        M is the total number of points to test
    l1 : numpy.array
        Array of shape (2,) indicating the first point standing on the line
    l2 : numpy.array
        Array of shape (2,) indicating the second point standing on the line
    threshold : float
        Maximum distance allowed between line and points
        
    Returns
        numpy.array
        Array of shape (M,) with True/False indicating whether the points in `a`
        are within/outside the rectangle around the line
    """
    distances = np.abs(np.cross(a - l1, a - l2)) / np.linalg.norm(l1 - l2)
    return (distances < threshold)
```

If you want to return the actual distances instead of a True/False array, just make the function return the `distances` object.

---

#### Example

```
# points on the line
p1 = np.array([298358.3258395831, 5625243.628060675])
p2 = np.array([298401.1779180078, 5625347.074197255])

# array of points to test
my_arr = np.array([
    [298359.3258395831, 5625243.628060675],
    [298368.3258395831, 5625243.628060675],
    [(p1[0] + p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2]
])

dist_array_line(my_arr, p1, p2, threshold=5.)
# array([ True, False,  True])
```