# Find perpendicular distance (vector) from a point to a straight line in 3D space

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62367575/17471060), I would like to calculate the perpendicular distance (in vector format instead of just magnitude) from a point to a straight line in 3D space.

The above mentioned equation does give the magnitude.

```
import numpy as np
norm = np.linalg.norm

p1 = np.array([0,0,0])
p2 = np.array([10,0,3])

p3 = np.array([6, -3, 5])

ppDist = np.abs(norm(np.cross(p2-p1, p1-p3)))/norm(p2-p1)
print(ppDist) # 4.28888043816146
```

`ppDist` vector in reality would be `(0.8807339448,3,-2.935779817)` such that its `norm()` is `4.288880438`

Here's a quick visualization -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find [projection](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html) of P13 vector on P12 and the vector difference of P13 from the projection would be the perpendicular vector.

```
P12 = p2-p1
P13 = p3-p1

proj_13over12 = np.dot(P13, P12)*P12/norm(P12)**2 # array([6.88073394, 0.        , 2.06422018])
perpendicular = proj_13over12 - P13

print(perpendicular) # [ 0.88073394  3.         -2.93577982]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach. Note that `np.linalg.norm(P12)**2` is equivalent to `np.dot(P12, P12)`, but the later is faster to compute than the former (due to the implicit square root to compute and internal Numpy overheads).

Answer (score 0):

```
python
import numpy as np

def distance_point_to_line(p1, p2, p3):
    v = p2 - p1
    w = p3 - p1
    proj_w_v = np.dot(w, v) / np.dot(v, v) * v
    u = w - proj_w_v
    d = np.linalg.norm(u)
    p = p3 - u
    return d, p
```

Comment: your perpendicular vector returns `array([6.88073394, 0 , 2.06422018]))`, by apparent observation of the input, you could figure out that `y` value of the vector must be `3` not `0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a slightly altered solution to [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76645327/12131013). This is because in OP's solution, the meaning of what they call `proj_13over12` is missing. What we want from the projection is actually the point that lies on the line defined by `p1` and `p2` which creates a vector perpendicular to that vector when connecting that point with `p3`. In the special case here where `p1 = (0,0,0)`, we get that result, but the value does not change when the points are moved. For example, with the given points, the perpendicular point is at `[6.88073394, 0., 2.06422018]`. But if we translate all the points by 1 in each direction, we should get a perpendicular point that was translated by the same amount, but we do not.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

p1 = np.array([0, 0, 0]) + 1
p2 = np.array([10, 0, 3]) + 1
p3 = np.array([6, -3, 5]) + 1

P12 = p2-p1
P13 = p3-p1

proj_13over12 = np.dot(P13, P12)*P12/norm(P12)**2 
print(proj_13over12) # still [6.88073394, 0., 2.06422018]
```

I'm going to use some different notation that makes more sense to me. First, the *vector* that connects `p1` to `p2` will be called `v1` (for vector 1), and the vector connecting `p1` to `p2` will be called `v2`. The result of the projection will be called `projv2_v1` (this somewhat mirrors the common notation where the vector being projected onto is a subscript of the word "proj"). The perpendicular point will be called `pperp`.

We compute the projection using the equation `v1 (v1 dot v2)/norm(v1)^2`, which can also be written as `v1 (v1 dot v2)/(v1 dot v1)`. (Mathematical interlude: The projection works because `v1/norm(v1)` gives a unit vector in the `v1` direction while `(v1 dot v2)/norm(v1)` gives the magnitude of the `v2` vector that is in the `v1` direction.)  Now, after computing the projection, `pperp` is found by adding `p1` back (we created the vectors by taking the difference with `p1`, essentially translating everything to the origin, so this step translates back to the actual location in space). And then the distance is found by finding the norm of the vector connecting `p1` to `pperp`. With these changes, the results all have simple physical interpretations.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

p1 = np.array([0,0,0])
p2 = np.array([10,0,3])
p3 = np.array([6, -3, 5])

v1 = p2 - p1
v2 = p3 - p1
projv2_v1 = np.dot(v1,v2)*v1/np.dot(v1, v1)
pperp = projv2_v1 + p1
print(pperp) # [6.88073394, 0., 2.06422018]
dist = norm(pperp - p3)
print(dist)  # 4.28888043816146
```

[image]

Now, if we were to translate all the points as before, we get `pperp =  [7.88073394, 1., 3.06422018]`, which makes sense because it would also be translated the same amount.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please note that projv2_v1 is a vector (start=p1, end=pperp vector end point) whereas pperp vector itself got start=origin i.e. 0,0,0.  [link](https://i.imgur.com/f2RBnmk.png)

Comment: @betagreen I agree that `projv2_v1` is a vector, but I'd consider `pperp` a point, which is why I named it like I did.